# How to change result of type(object)?

Tags: python, string, oop

I'm using a 3rd-party Python module that does something horrible, like:

```
def foo(x):
    if type(x) is str:
        do_useful_thing()
```

I've got a class that subclasses `str`:

```
class mystr(str):
   ....
```

I'd like to call `foo()` on a `mystr` instance, but it fails because `type(mystr) != type(str)`. Is there any way I can make my class so that `type(mystr) == type(str)` and hence get `foo` to accept it?

I know the *right* solution is for the 3rd-party module to use `isinstance`, but unfortunately I cannot change that.

Comment: Would it work to call `foo(str(x))`?

Comment: The only possible solution I know of is to monkey-patch `type` in the third-party module's namespace.

Comment: Or monkeypatch `foo` altogether.

Comment: Sure, monkey patch `type`, what can go wrong... -.-

Comment: If you monkey-patch it *only* in that one module, and that module itself doesn't do any "interesting" metaprogramming (e.g. it doesn't contain any metaclasses), you're probably fine. Creating a *useful* monkeypatch replacement for `type` is the hard part here.

Comment: @DanielPryden: You can't monkey-patch it in only the one module due to `sys.modules` caching (but it's probably safe to anyway if patched properly).

Comment: Monkey patching is unmaintainable at best and can lead to undefined behaviour and horrible hell at worst. I advice either contacting lib creators or changing the lib.

Comment: @martineau: I'm proposing not to modify `builtins.type` but to *add* a `type` member to the third-party module. References to `type` within the third-party module's code will look up from the local module namespace. That doesn't affect all modules, right? (But yes, it is still a global effect.)

Comment: That said, I'm with @freakish: the *correct* answer here is to change the third-party library.

Comment: add an attribute in your class `mystr`: 

```class mystr(str):
    def __init__(self):
        self.type = str
    
test=mystr()

print(test.type)```

Comment: @DanielPryden: I think that's making a whole lot of assumptions about the third-party module...

Comment: @AngeloMendes: That isn't what the question is asking for, since `type(x)` never looks for an `x.type` attribute. Also, if you have an *answer*, please post it in the "Your Answer" box below rather than as a comment.

Comment: @xorsyst: Is the library open source? If so, send them a pull request. The worst they can do is say no. But my guess is that they probably would accept a change from `type(x) is str` to `isinstance(x, str)` without any argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting as an answer the consensus from the comments section: Even if it were possible to do this sort of thing, it's a really bad idea. Even if you got it to work *some* of the time, it would cause weird things to break somewhere else.

The right answer is to reach out to the author of the third-party library and to try to resolve it with them. Or, if possible, to fork that library and maintain your own version that doesn't have this restriction.

Comment: I agree. Getting the author of the third-party to do Python type-check "properly" using `isinstance()` would likely be al that was needed (and relatively easy to convince them to do).

Answer (score 4):

You could hijack the `type` builtin for the 3rd-party module.

So if the 3rd-party code is this:

```
# bar.py (a.k.a, crappy 3rd-party code)
def foo(x):
    if type(x) is str:
        return True
    return False
```

You could write something like this:

```
import bar

class MyStr(str):
    pass

# Returns False.... BOOO!
bar.foo(MyStr())

def fake_type(a):
    if isinstance(a, MyStr):
        return str
    else:
        return type(a)

bar.type = fake_type

# This should now return True :-)
bar.foo(MyStr())
```

And don't forget to go tell the the 3rd-party to fix their code so that you can get rid of this hack later.

Comment: This is basically what I suggested in my comment, so have an upvote. Of course, as was discussed in the comments, that will fail if anything in `bar` uses `type` as a class and not a function (e.g. subclassing `type` to make a new metaclass).

Answer (score 1):

It will depend on how you have subclassed str, but it's possible that all you need to do is temporarily typecast back to str...

```
class mystr(str):
    def has_e(self):
        if 'e' in self:
            print('True')

def foo(value):
    if type(value) == str:
        print('You Rock')
    else:
        print('You Roll')

if __name__=='__main__':
    a = mystr('hi mom')
    a.has_e()
    foo(str(a))
```

Comment: This is useful but only if `foo()` does not act on the `a` instance and merely uses the str value for something, because `str(a)` will be a different object.

Comment: Agreed. One should be careful